# Why caching ajax request is not working?

Tags: ajax, caching, prototypejs

I have a large json data object (over 300K uncompressed, 40K gzipped) which is used on every page of my internal system. I want to fetch it every 15 minutes. In this time user will probably visit tens of pages of my system.

The HTTP Response headers in Firebug look like:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=899, public
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  44017
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-2
Date    Tue, 04 Dec 2012 16:21:45 GMT
Expires Tue, 04 Dec 12 17:36:45 +0100
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=99
Last-Modified   Tue, 04 Dec 12 17:21:45 +0100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
Set-Cookie  user_auth=xxx; expires=Wed, 12-Dec-2012 16:21:45 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com 
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Genaration-Time   0.13282179832458 sec.
X-Genarator vCRM 3.1 (c) Veracomp S.A.
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
```

The cache headers are set to 15 minutes in future, but neither Chrome nor Firefox caches it. 
The Firebug says this about cache:

```
Data Size   44017
Device  disk
Expires Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100
Fetch Count 5
Last Fetched    Tue Dec 04 2012 17:21:45 GMT+0100
Last Modified   Tue Dec 04 2012 17:21:45 GMT+0100
```

**It seams the Expires header is ignored, but why?**

This sould not mattery, but I better write, that the content type is text/html, so the server can gzip it, but in reality the content is JSON.

I am using Prototype.js to request this. I set the request header:

```
Cache-control: max-age=900
```

Prototype.js does not add any cache buster parameter to the url. 
I am using PHP with Zend_Framework to set serve the response.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `Pragma: no-cache` in your response? http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32 (HTTP/1.1 caches SHOULD treat "Pragma: no-cache" as if the client had sent "Cache-Control: no-cache")

Comment: aaargh.... I had missed it... I wonder what sets this header. I do not set it explicitly. Maybe the PHP config. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

As @Victor pointed out, I had the "Pragma: no-cache" header set. The header was somehow set by PHP. I worked with our webserver admin and we had managed to unset the header with Apache.
Still it was not enough. Our framework sets cookies with every page refresh and I could not turn it of. Browsers did not want to cache the requests which set cookies. We had to unset the Set-Cookie headers too. 
Finally this two unsets allowed us to enable cache:

```
<LocationMatch "(?i)/url/we/want/to/be/cached/.+">
       Header unset Pragma
       Header unset Set-Cookie
</LocationMatch>
```